# How can I make my textbox accept inputs until 11 numbers?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my code that I want my textbox to only accept eleven numbers and stop when it has eleven.

```
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Comment: MaxLength property? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

Just check the length of the text? Something along the lines of:

```
if(MyTextBox.TextLength < 11)
{
    // keep accepting numbers
}
```

Or (I'm not super familiar with `Winforms`) you can set the [MaxLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength?view=netframework-4.7.2) for the textbox.

Comment: I guess there's just one drawback, you can still paste more than 11 into the TextBox if you set `MaxLength=11`. But i don't know if that's an issue.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter  You can paste a string longer than `MaxLength`, but only a `MaxLength` number of chars are actually inserted in a Textbox/RichTextBox. The Text property will reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MaskedTextBox` and set the `Mask` 99999999999